# Must a L3 switch always have an IP address?

Tags: switch, local-area-network, subnet

I have 3 L3 switches connected as shown below:
[image]

All devices are in the same `subnet` and have `IP addresses` : 192.168.150.X/24

Shouldn't the switches be able to forward traffic without requiring `IP addresses`/`gateway addresses`, since I'm not crossing subnets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If correctly configured then there's no actual L3 routing going on here - only L2 switching, so they wouldn't need IP interfaces (well other than for management obviously), but you don't provide enough information to speak about the specifics of this setup.

Comment: it's not really a setup. I'm just arguing with a friend about the max. amount of devices one can connect in such a setup. I say `256-2=254`and he says `256-2-3=251`, because of the L3 switches

Comment: You're right, it's 254 - well technically 255 because you *can* use .0 if you REALLY wanted to make life hard for yourself - but in this setup there's no need for routing whatsoever - in real life you would have IPs but in a dumb network like this you are right.

Comment: It seems, I just became 10 Euros richer :). Thank you

Comment: Btw, how would the `ARP table` be managed this way? If data from `device0` must be forwarded to `device1`, `switch_1` won't find an entry in its `ARP table` with the `MAC address` of `device1`, would it? How does it know, that it must forward the packet to `switch3`?

Comment: Well again ARP is a L3 component, if you have a purely L2 switched environment then ARP is of no/little use. This is very basic networking stuff sorry and this site isn't for beginners.

Comment: I meant `CAM tables` not `ARP`. But thanks anyway

Comment: Look this is very basic L2 switching here, and this site isn't a teaching site, go read something about this as it's really fundamental stuff that everyone else on this site 'just gets'. Sorry to be negative but we haven't time here to teach everyone every aspect of the ABC's of their jobs.

Answer (score 2):

It's 256 -2. The fact that the switches exist doesn't reduce the number of available ip addresses.

The switches don't require ip addresses. If you did assign them ip addresses then that would be subtracted from the 254.

If you assign an ip address to the switches then that reduces the number of remaining available ip addresses, just as it does when assigning an ip address to any other device.

Answer (score 1):

**ANSWER:**

In the above configuration the switches in the design are **functioning as layer two switches, not layer three**. In the simplest implementation they are not performing any Layer 3 tasks, though in some circumstances there might be useful Layer 3 features you might want to implement depending on the specific design. Some of those features might require an IP Address to use (*see Best Practices below*).

Only in cases where the switches are bridging different network segments would IP Addresses be required. In Layer 2, the routing (*though we call it switching*) is performed using MAC Addresses. Between networks, IP Addresses are needed to properly route the data.

A Layer 3 Switch does not need to function as such. It can also function as a Layer 2, though it would be a waste of money to use it this way. A layer three cisco switch can run 3-5 times the cost of a layer two switch with similar number of ports.

As stated, your formula is typically considered correct **allowing for a total of 254 usable addresses**. The network address CAN be used (.0), but its a headache. In that scenario you can have 255 usable. The broadcast address (.255) is never usable. Of course all this information and addresses depnd on subnet size. For subnets smaller/larger than 256 (/24) adjust your numbers accordingly.

**BEST PRACTICE:**

**That being said, the switches usually WILL have IP Addresses assigned to them**. *WHY?* Remote management, especially if they are enabled for SSH. Depending on the configuration, this isn't strictly necessary, their are lots of protocols that can propagate settings between switches without the need for IP Addressing. But the most versatile usage would have an IP Address configured for the switches.

With this assumption, you would have 251 remaining usable addresses (or 252 if using the network address).